# Relation between $\mathbb{C}$-automorphisms and Möbius transformations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, complex-geometry

Today in my Algebraic Ecuations course, the proffesor mentioned that while there is only one field automorphism (the trivial one) in $\mathbb{R}$, there are infinite field automorphisms in $\mathbb{C}$. I was curious, is this somewhat related to Möbius transformations? (also known as linear transformations, ie $T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ where $a,b,c,d,z\in \mathbb{C}$). Intuitively, I think this as composing in some way with the stereographic projection in the same way one can do it when talking about the fundamental group of the circunference. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean "field automorphism"? While your tags make it seem like that, your post says "only one group automorphism". That is not true; for example, $x \mapsto 2x$ is a non-trivial group automorphism of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the post now. Thanks

Comment: The automorphisms of $\Bbb C(T)/\Bbb C$ are Mobius transformations of $T$. The automorphisms of $\Bbb C/\Bbb Q$ are very, very "wild." In principle, we can embed $\Bbb C(T)$ as a subfield of $\Bbb C$ and extend its automorphisms, but this will be a very unnatural (and likely impossible-to-write-down or explicitly-describe) way to put $PSL(2,\Bbb C)$ in ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb C/\Bbb Q)$. Out of curiosity, what are you talking about with stereographic projection and fundamental group of circumference?

Comment: Well, the first proof of the fundamental group of the circunference used the stereographic projection to get to know the homotopy classes, not explicitly, but used the existance of it as an inverse of the parametrization if I remember correctly. I wondered if it had any relations since I am really interested in algebraic topology

Comment: The word "circumference" is reserved for circles (which are curves), not spheres (which are surfaces). There is a relationship between Mobius transformations and stereographic projection - indeed, under these projections, $SU(2)$'s Mobius transformations act by 3D rotations of the sphere! But these aren't related to the field automorphisms of $\Bbb C/\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not true. Consider the conjugation map $\phi:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ given by $\phi(z) = \bar{z}$.

One can see that this is indeed a field homomorphism and is clearly bijective since $\phi^2$ is identity. However, $\phi$ is not holomorphic.

On the other hand, all the Möbius transformations are holomorphic and thus, composing them with the stereographic projection also won't give you conjugation.